# External IP address doesn't change with VPN enabled

Tags: c#, .net

My application start and automatically run a thread with this code that run every 5 seconds

```
string urlAddress = "http://icanhazip.com/";

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader readStream = null;

                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(response.CharacterSet))
                    readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
                else
                    readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));

                ip = readStream.ReadToEnd();

                response.Close();
                readStream.Close();
            }
```

After I run a vpn my ip is still the normal one, how can I get the new ip that was assigned by vpn? Are the request made by same ip, even after it was changed?

Comment: Does it work if you set the VPN before running this code?

Comment: Why do you think it would be any different ? you still have a network card i presume, that is still connected to a router, and possibly to the internet, why would a vpn change any of those ip addresses? How are you detecting your IP address (or any ip for that matter), and why do you think it should change?

Comment: Yeah , the ip changes even if I run the code in a while(true), but when I run it as a Thread, ip dosn't change.

Comment: What ip? there are many ips passed around on a computer which one are you talking about? where are you getting it from, how do you tell its not changed. please be specific

Comment: Sorry, I get it from a request to this link "http://icanhazip.com/" , it's about the external ip adress, when the program start I assign to a variable the current ip after that in the code above I have an if statement that compare the old ip with the current one that request is pulling from here http://icanhazip.com/

Comment: your connection may be reusing. try keep alive false in httpwebrequest.

Comment: Vilsad , thank you that was the problem.